# Casting away constness - array and pointer types ambiguity in the standard

Tags: c++, casting, c++17, language-lawyer

Below you can see three different variants of `reinterpret_cast`, which doesn't have the ability to cast away constness. The definition of "casting away constness" is in [this section of the standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/expr.const.cast#8), and it specifically details pointer types, not array types. According to the standards, for multilevel pointers we keep checking for qualifier downcasts until we hit a non-pointer type(which array is). Refer to the following, which is also available in [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/YqzY99).

```cpp
int * const *__restrict (*const *__restrict a)[2] {}; // ptr -> ptr -> arr -> ptr -> ptr -> int
reinterpret_cast<const double *__restrict (*const *__restrict)[2]>(a); // ptr -> ptr -> arr -> ptr -> double
reinterpret_cast<double *__restrict (*const *__restrict)[2]>(a);

// Fine because we've reached an array type
volatile int* const (* * const x) [2] {}; // ptr -> ptr -> arr -> ptr -> int
reinterpret_cast<int * * const * * const>(x); // ptr -> ptr -> ptr -> ptr -> int

// Fine because we've reached an array type
volatile int* const * const * * const y {}; // ptr -> ptr -> arr -> ptr -> int
reinterpret_cast<int * * const (* * const)[2]>(y); // ptr -> ptr -> ptr -> ptr -> int
```

In the later two passing test cases, we **clearly dropped qualifiers past the arr type level**, and we're not casting away constness. In the top section, I thought checking for "casting away const"ness is supposed to stop at the 3rd level (both array type). This isn't the case and it produced an error. Am I misreading something from the standard? It seems like GCC and Clang both have this behavior for C++17.

Comment: The draft you link is not C++17 draft. https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.const.cast#def:casting_away_constness

Comment: Ah got it. They used the term similar here which includes array. Makes sense, thank you!

Comment: This was [CWG330](http://wg21.link/cwg330)

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I've answered the question because of your help :) I see the exact case listed in the defects there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Language Lawyer for pointing this out, but because the C++17 draft states that if two types are similar they can be explicitly casted between using `const_cast`. A similar type is one where every level of the multilevel pointer/array type is the same, i.e. at i-th level we have one of the four:

> “pointer to”, “pointer to member of class Ci of type”, “array of Ni”, or “array of unknown bound of”

In this case, because the entire type is similar, in C++17 the first example fails. In the latter two cases, the types are similar up to array of Ni vs. pointer to, and thus the rest of the types are truncated in the consideration of "casting away constness".